# How to choose a database for Android application?

Tags: android, mobile, chat

I want to create a Chat Android Application, but I am stuck with database choosing.

What is the best database option for such application? Thank you!

Comment: what database options have you found so far?

Comment: SQL, Firebase Database.

Comment: you need to consider how you want to certralise the messages. And how the messages would sync between devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest [Room-DB](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) because It works very well with [Pagination](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging) and [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel).
It is also ORM and it is realy usefull and fast to use.